# Three.js: How to reuse geometry/material for multiple entities?

Tags: javascript, loading, three.js, assets

I have a multiplayer game where I want to render a player entity for each player, all using the same geometry and material. Ideally I would like to add a player mash to the scene when I create a new player object (holding the state of the player etc).

How can those player objects reuse the same geometry/material? My biggest problem is that the geometry gets loaded asynchronously with a callback, so I can't just assign it to a variable before initializing the players and use it to create the mashes (which is basically what I do with the textures, as it seems).

Is there some sort of "global" asset manager I could use? Maybe even preload all the assets I need for the game before starting with the game logic / creating the scene?

Comment: Probably won't help to write walls of text about that. Messed arround with how to load stuff for hours now, but everything I try just gets horribly complex/doesn't work properly. The topic got discussed on https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1751 but it seems like none of those got really implemented yet. Next thing I'm going to try is using THREE.SceneLoader to preload all my assets and put them in an object for use (which is the only slightly complex "loading" example I could find).

Comment: SceneLoader seems to work quite good for preloading and even initializing textures, materials, geometries etc. Think I'll use that until my assets grow too big to preload all (and even then, I'll probably use another scene). Will give an example on how it works tomorrow for others searching for that kind of stuff.